# Не видит путь Си

Tags: c, exe, path, reverse-engineering

Я пытаюсь достать файлы из одного exe файла.
На гитхабе нашёл программу для моей задачи, но она никак не может съесть нужный файл.

Ссылка на гитхаб [J2e](https://gist.github.com/HaoQinLandv/57e5fc7c3b1174f7020a044d7883b981)

17 строчку переделал на путь. путь верный(писал проверку)

`char* fileName = "C:\\Users\\Agnia\\Desktop\\j2e\\sadik-8.05.exe";`

После запуска выдаёт лог ERROR: File not found!

Проверка на существование файла

```
DWORD dwAttrib;
dwAttrib = GetFileAttributes(path1);

    if(dwAttrib == 0xFFFFFFFF){
        printf("Error getting attributes.\n");
    }

    if(dwAttrib & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE){
        printf("File is an archive.\n");
    }
```

Вывод -  File is an archive

В чём может быть ошибка. Куда копать?

Comment: попробуйте строку `hExe = LoadLibrary(TEXT(fileName));` заменить на `hExe = LoadLibrary(fileName);` В целом, применение макроса TEXT  к переменной ни к чему хорошему не приводит, но у Вас скорее всего отключен режим юникода. А вот строку `printf("ERROR: File not found!");` лучше написать где то как `printf("ERROR: File not found!, %d", GetLastError());` и мы узнаем, почему именно оно не смогло.

Comment: @KoVadim 
Изменил, как ты сказал. Убрал Text
И изменил вывод error

Вывод - 
ERROR: File not found!, 193

Comment: LoadLibrary может возвращать эту ошибку, не только потому что отсутствует загружаемый файл, но и потому что отстствуют  зависимые DLL, необходимые для запуска этого файла...  Попробуйте посмотреть каких dll не хватает. http://dependencywalker.com/

Comment: @KoVadim Спасибо за отклик, нашёл проблему

Comment: @Chorkov Спасибо за отклик, нашёл проблему

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка найдена. Данная программа не поддерживает 64-битные exe.
Только 32.